# Is there a function in VB.NET that gets a path object from a given directory object?

Tags: vb.net

I'm writing a function like this:

```
Private Function mostRecent(ByVal folder As Directory) As Date

    'function to convert the given directory param as a path obj

    Dim foldPathStr = Path.GetFullPath(foldPath)

    Dim createDate As Date = Directory.GetCreationTime(foldPathStr)
    Dim writeDate As Date = Directory.GetLastWriteTime(foldPathStr)
    Dim readDate As Date = Directory.GetLastAccessTime(foldPathStr)

    If createDate > writeDate And createDate > readDate Then
        Return createDate
    ElseIf writeDate > createDate And writeDate > readDate Then
        Return writeDate
    ElseIf readDate > createDate And readDate > writeDate Then
        Return readDate
    End If

End Function
```

I'd like to fill in that commented line with a built-in command, if available. If not, guess I'll change the parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) is a static class - it's never instantiated; there's *never* an instance of a `Path` object.

That's assuming we're talking about the same `Path` class here... I'm somewhat surprised to see [`Directory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.aspx) as a parameter type, given that that's a static class too. Are you sure you don't mean [`DirectoryInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx)? Or is this a VB class which has been given the same name as a `System.IO` class just to confuse unwary C# developers?

If it *is* `DirectoryInfo`, I think you just want the [`FullName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.fullname.aspx) property.